# Docker compose wait for without sleep command

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I've read lots for similar topics; 
For example this: 
[Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y) etc.

So, I'm trying to implement a wait for only using compose and health checks.

I have only one docker-compose file. There is a section for the app and for test for this app.

Test (service) can be executed only when app(jar, db etc) will be ready. 
Also after test (service) execution, I want to get status for this execution via $?

So my compose file is next:

```
version: "2.1"
networks:
  myNetwork:
services:
  rabbitmq:
   ... 
    networks:
      - myNetwork
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "rabbitmqctl", "status"]
      interval: 100s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 10
  app:
    ...
    depends_on:
      rabbitmq:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - myNetwork
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "wget", "http://localhost:8080/ping"]
      interval: 100s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 10

  tests:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: TestDocker
    depends_on:
      app:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - myNetwork
```

Im trying to run:

```
docker-compose up -d app && docker-compose run tests;
```

or

```
docker-compose run tests
```

But  `docker-compose run tests` don't waits for  condition: service_healthy; (app and rabbitmq containers is started but service_healthy was not checked);

**And this is the problem.**

When I do something like this:

```
  docker-compose up -d app && sleep 20 && docker-compose run tests;
```

So is there is any possibility to do sleep or wait for, for command: docker-`compose run tests` ?

Comment: Can you confirm the Docker and Docker Compose versions you are running?

Comment: Docker version 17.03.1-ce, build c6d412e

docker-compose version 1.11.2, build f963d76f